# Is there a way to gitignore all current extra files?

Tags: git

I have a set of files in a git repository which I want to ignore.

I know the simplest solution: Add them all to `.gitignore` manually.

I do not want to ignore all further files, so `path/*` is not an option. If I somehow could use `path/*`, let git parse it, and then save the current "extra files", that would be perfect, but as far as I'm concerned there is no easy way to do that.

The alternative would be to make a script which greps the filenames after `git status`' untracked files, and sends the output to `.gitignore`, which might be what I will end up doing.

Any tips are appreciated.

Related, but not my main question: Is there a reason why git doesn't include a `git ignore` command?

Comment: You've already identified several possible solutions to your problem. Was there a specific problem when you tried to implement one of them?

Comment: @mkrieger1 The only problem I have with adding the files manually/through a script is that I feel I'm missing an obvious cleaner way to do what I intend to do.

Comment: You can just copy/paste the output of `git status` into `.gitignore` in a text editor. It doesn't even have to be a script.

Comment: The script would be something like `git status -s | awk '{ if ($1 == "??") print $2 }' >> .gitignore`. It's subjective if that's a script or not I guess.

Comment: Okay, and why don't you just do it like this then? What's the problem?

Comment: The fact that I can get something to work does not mean that's the best or only solution. I ask questions hoping to learn something.

Comment: you have a clean and stable enough solution ; you could replace `git status | grep/awk ...` with `git ls-files --exclude-standard -o`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [An] alternative would be to make a script which greps the filenames after `git status`' untracked files, and sends the output to `.gitignore`, which might be what I will end up doing.

For writing scripts, always try to use plumbing commands.

With `git status` there is the `--porcelain` option<sup>1</sup> to turn it into a plumbing command.  Consider also using `git ls-files --others` (`-o` for short) but note that you would want to add the `--exclude-standard` option.

> Related, but not my main question: Is there a reason why git doesn't include a `git ignore` command?

Define what, precisely, it would do; write one; and submit it and see if you can get it accepted. :-)

---

<sup>1</sup>As always, I express my own bafflement as to why this option is not spelled `--plumbing`.

Comment: It seems like `git ls-files -o` does exactly what I want, and I never even knew git had this command (even after probably seeing it in many other scripts). On `git ignore`, I might actually submit it and see what happens. :P ¹: Porcelain, because we have to treat things with care during transport.

Comment: @mazunki : empasis on the `--exclude-standard` option to `git ls-files` : by default, `git ls-files -o` does not take into account the existing `.gitignore` files in your repo, and lists the content of already excluded files and directories.

Comment: Would this mean that I get doubles in my `.gitignore` file if I don't use it?

Comment: @mazunki : yes, possibly

Answer (score 0):

Dirty script which adds all untracked files into gitignore:

`git status -s | awk '{ if ($1 == "??") print $2 }' >> .gitignore`

In short format of `git status`, files are printed per line, with no fluff. The first column tells the status of the files listed. Specifically, untracked files are `??`. Read up on `git status --help` for other combinations.

Matching on first column, and printing second column with awk, we append each line into .gitignore.

There might be a better or cleaner solution, but this works.

Answer (score -1):

Finally, in alternative you could exclude everything and just force add what you know you want.

```
path/*               # exclude all
!path/keep_this      # but not this
!path/keep_that      # and that
```

Comment: From a clean-code perspective, this is far from optimal. The situation I had was that I had a bunch of images and text data mixed with the source files for some image manipulation on my local machine. While this was optimal for testing, I did not want git to even know about these images. I claim your solution is not clean since I'd have to manually re-keep all the source files. That's counterintuitive. I'd dare say doing something like `path/*.png; path/*.jpg; path/*.dat; path/*.out` would be "the best way" to do this manually with globs, but is not portable for other/all scenarios.

Comment: if you committed those images, everybody cloning the repo would not only know about those but also have a copy of those. Consider adding this to .git/info/exclude if that's your concern. From a versioning stand point it makes sense: this folder is irrelevant, but these listed files. But since this is opinion-based, I shall just point it out as alternative and move along.